# d3js get <path d="NaN"> when splitting my code in object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a map with d3.js.
I already did it a first time and it worked, but now I try to split my code to make it easier to read. When i split it i get NaN instead of position in my path.

Here is a link to my repo if you want the full version:
https://github.com/TheWalkingDesign/map-plugin

Thank for the help, I'm stuck with this.

```
this.projection = setProjection(
        this.options.projection,
        this.options.center,
        this.options.translate,
        this.options.scale
        );

    this.path = d3.geo.path().projection(this.projection);

    this.svg = d3.select("#"+this.options.mapid).append("svg")
        .attr("width", this.width)
        .attr("height", this.height)
        .call(this.zoom); // enable zoomable on svg

    this.g = this.svg.append("g");

    drawMap(this.topo, this.path, this.g, this.options.mapid);

function setProjection(type, center, translate, scale) {
    var projection;
    if (type === 'equirectangular') {
        projection = d3.geo.equirectangular();
    } else if (type === 'mercator') {
        projection : d3.geo.mercator();
    }
    projection.center(center) // bug when set to 0, 0
        .translate(translate) // center the map in the container
        .scale(scale); // scale the map to fit the width of container
    return projection;
};

function drawMap(topo, path, container, mapid) {
    // Draw countries geometry on map
    var countries = container.append('g').attr('id', mapid + '_countries').selectAll('.' + mapid + '_country').data(topo);

    countries.enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", mapid + '_country')
        .attr("d", path);

};
```

Comment: Would be great to check the original version; the code as is seems to be ok.

Comment: Hi, I add a link to the repo with both the normal version and the new one I try to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so finally I find my error.
I was using element.innerWidth to find the width of my div, but I'm not using Jquery so I had to use element.offsetWidth.

Both my width and height property were undefined so I wasn't able to create a good projection used by the path.

Sorry about that and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing *path* inside the scope of drawMap that's why it can't find this.projection.

Try this:

```
this.path = d3.geo.path().projection(this.projection).bind(this);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to add .bind(this); unfortunately I still have the same error.